Picking the right correlation method in data that has many zero values
I want to calculate the correlation between two genes that I have in my data. What I did so far is calculate Pearson or Spearman correlation (I rely more on Spearman since there is no linear relationship between the genes).
However - Many cells have zero expression for gene1, gene2, or both, which leads to inaccuracies and biases in the correlation.
So I have some options -

I can keep only the cells that express both genes (this will remove lots of cells) and then recalculate the correlations.
I should keep the zeros because it's part of the biology
Use some other method that is less sensitive to zeros, such as cosine similarity maybe ?

Here is a plot for example - each dot is a cell, X axis is expression of gene1, and Y axis us expression of gene2 :


Are these single-cell data? Are the units on the two axes some type of normalized RNAseq counts, or something else? The lines on the scatter plot suggest that there might be different clusters; have you done any t-SNE/UMAP or similar clustering based on the overall data set (which presumably contains other gene expression values)? I suspect that a single correlation (of any type) won't capture what the data can teach you.

@EdM Yes this is scRNA-seq data indeed. It is normalized and log transformed. And yes I did what you suggested, actually what you see in the plot all are the same cell type, and I am trying to see the correlation of some genes in this cell type specifically. In the plot you can see some dots (cells) perform perfect lines which further drives to me wonder what is going on here..

First, you say you use Spearman more than Pearson because there is "no linear relationship between the genes".  If there is no linear relationship, then correlation is not what you want. Spearman looks for a linear relationship in the ranks, rather than the absolute values. Also, your graph shows that there is at least some linear relationship. And note that, in your case, Pearson and Spearman give identical values.
Second, zeroes do not lead to "inaccuracies and biases" in the correlation, but they may mean that correlation is not what you want.
Third, what measure you should use depends on what, precisely, you are trying to measure. Maybe there is no measure that captures what you want. Maybe correlation does capture it. Maybe some other measure is better. Maybe you need a more complex description of the relationship that includes the 0's as a separate case.
What do you want to find?
Fourth, your graph has a lot of overplotting; you could reduce this by e.g. using smaller symbols, or using unfilled circles, or other means. I wrote a SAS paper abut this (but it could easily be used in R or other programs). The title is "Scatterplots: Basics, enhancements, problems, and solutions" at various SAS conferences.

No single correlation coefficient will capture the gene-expression patterns in your data. You have many cells that seem only to express one or the other of these two genes. As these are RNA sequencing data from single cells (scRNA-seq) based originally on actual counts of individual transcripts, many of the cells with zero apparent expression might represent a failure to detect expression that's really there rather than true zero expression.
For display, you might consider a two-dimensional contour plot or heat map like those used in flow cytometry. That will show more directly the relative numbers of cells having different combinations of gene expression.
For analysis, one way to proceed is a hurdle model that first estimates the probability that one or both genes has 0 counts and then evaluates the co-expression (e.g., by correlation) in cells having both genes expressed. That would capture at least some major important parts of what your plot shows. I believe that there might be further ways to discriminate how many 0-count values are true 0 versus missed detection, based on the statistics of sampling individual transcripts from cells, but I'm not an expert on that.
I suspect that the line patterns in your data arise from your normalization method. Line patterns in two-dimensional plots typically indicate quantization of the underlying observations. With scRNA-seq, counts of individual transcripts for those two genes are a likely reason for quantization. It's hard to know from these normalized data, but I suspect that the individual raw counts for cells along those apparent lines will show just a few counts for each of these two genes. Normalization to something like counts per million transcripts from a cell could then lead to apparent lines in the plot from the cells, depending on the overall abundance used for normalization.
The plot looks like you have might have used methods designed for continuous data from bulk RNA-seq data on the normalized single-cell counts. If so, look into methods that work with the inherent count nature of the raw data, negative binomial models (perhaps along with zero-inflation or hurdle characteristics) that can account for the discrete nature of the data while taking the total number of observed transcripts per cell into account.
Finally, a warning about biology rather than statistics: even if all of the displayed cells are from a single cell type, they might not all be in the same phenotypic state. In particular, cells might be in different phases of the cell cycle, with the co-expression patterns of these two genes depending on the state of that cycle. With scRNA-seq data you can use expression patterns of other genes to estimate the cell-cycle status, and see whether the co-expression of these two genes is a function of cell cycle state.
